# jquery transfer effect not working for oppsite process

Tags: jquery

i have following code .
when click on #eve element it works but when i click on home link it is not working.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #eve{min-height: 200px;width: 200px;background-color: #666600;top: 57px;left: 212px}
        .ui-effects-transfer { border: 1px solid #9999ff }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="transfer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#eve").click(function () {
                $(this).effect("transfer",{to: $("#home")}, 500,function(){$(this).hide()});
            });
            $("#home").click(function () {
                $("#eve").show()
                $("#eve").effect("transfer",{to: $("#here")}, 500,function(){$("#eve").show()});
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Home
        end

Answer (score 0):

If #home is a link, you should remember that, the browser will be execute this link, so you cannot see effect.

Try:

```
$("#home").click(function () {
    $("#eve").show();
    $("#eve").effect("transfer",{to: $("#here")}, 500,function(){$("#eve").show()});
    return false;
});
```

or

```
$("#home").click(function (e) {
    $("#eve").show();
    $("#eve").effect("transfer",{to: $("#here")}, 500,function(){$("#eve").show()});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```